# Drupal, need to link an image-block to a node in colorbox format

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, colorbox

I am trying to make a block of image (in left sidebar of the home page) to link to a colorbox.

For example I have a block with an image in home page. All I want to do is that when I click there the colorbox open with the content-type, for example a gallery of images. I tried everything for two days, but I couldn't make it work. All I could do is to make the colorbox to work inside the node but no directly from the homepage, and less from an imageblock in the homepage.

I would be appreciated if anyone can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [Colorbox Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) module can be of help. That module enables you to open any page inside a colorbox modal without the header and footer.

In your use case you can make a link in the image block which looks likes this

```
<a class="colorbox-node" href="blogs/my-example?width=600&height=600">My Example</a>
```

When clicking the link, the link will open in a Colorbox modal. For more info on supported features and usage, take a look at the [module's project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node).

Comment: This is working but i cannot make the content to load, for example i want to display one image per slide, and no all the images in the same colorbox, it's any way to achieve this??

Comment: I think you need specify the colorbox formatter in de 'manage display' of that node's content type you're using. see this blogpost for an explanation: http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2013/using-colorbox-show-node-images-drupal-7

Comment: it's set, but when i go to the imageblock, it displays a colorbox with the content of the node i mean the two images and when i click on one of them another colorbox displays with one image per slide. What i want to achieve is to go to one image per slide directly and not display the node in the colorbox. Thank you.

Comment: ah ok :) Well, perhaps then you should look for a slideshow module, e.g. Views slideshow, to display content on that node.